# Show bookmarklet output in new tab

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a very easy problem (I guess) but it keeps me busy for quite a time.
When running this small snippet in my bookmarklet:

```
javascript:document.getElementById("detailPanel-body").innerHTML;
```

The current page will be changed to the output of the bookmarklet. However, what I want, is that the bookmarklet opens a new tab with the output of the javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use browsers where navigating to Data URI is not blocked (like Firefox), you can try this:

```js
javascript: {
  void window.open(`data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,${
    encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('detailPanel-body').innerHTML)
  }`);
}
```

If you use browsers where navigating to Data URI is blocked ([like Chrome](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM/GsIAQlemBQAJ)), you can try this:

```js
javascript: {
  void (window.open().document.body.textContent =
    document.getElementById('detailPanel-body').innerHTML);
}
```